# Python. ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль

Tags: python

Установил библиотеку `seaborn` через виртуальное окружение. Запускаю код `import seaborn as sns` , и выходит следующая ошибка. `ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.` в гугл накопал что нужно как вроде установить один из файлов .. с данного сайта https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal . Я скачал себе данный файл http://joxi.ru/MAjQZNDu4e31D2 . Но что делать дальше не понятно. У меня Python 3.7.2  и windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем как это лечится.
Удаляем библиотек `seaborn` далее  [переходим на сайт](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) скачиваем файл seaborn‑0.9.0‑py2.py3‑none‑any.whl  закидываем в папку проекта, и ставим библиотеку следующим образом: `pip install seaborn-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
Всё ок!

Comment: В дополнении к своему ответу хочу сказать следующее: У вас должно быть установлено Visual Studio с компонентом среды разработки Python. Код можете запускать откуда угодно. Данное ПО должно быть просто установлено. Я например запускаю из Sublime